# wrapping process.nextTick leads to Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to wrap process.nextTick function but that leads to recursion.

```
var actual = process.nextTick;

process.nextTick = function(callback)
{
console.log('next tick called');
actual.apply(this, arguments);
}

console.log('starts');
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('set timeout called');
}, 100);
```

this code produces

```
starts
next tick called
next tick called
...
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

can anyone explain the workflow???

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much sure that `console.log()` is calling [process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args) and causing the recursion.

Have a look on the following example:

```
var counter = 0;
var actual = process.nextTick;

process.nextTick = function ()
{
    counter++;
    actual.apply(this, arguments);
}

console.log('starts ...'); // This will increment counter with 1, counter = 1
process.nextTick(function () {
    console.log('nextTick callback'); // This will increment counter with 1, counter = 3
    console.log(counter); // This will increment counter with 1, counter = 4
});
console.log('something else ...'); // This will increment counter with 1, counter = 2

/*
 *   OUTPUT 
 */
starts ...
something else ...
nextTick callback
4
```

Now if we remove one of the `console.log()` calls, we can see the following:

```
var counter = 0;
var actual = process.nextTick;

process.nextTick = function ()
{
    counter++;
    actual.apply(this, arguments);
}

console.log('starts ...'); // This will increment counter with 1, counter = 1
process.nextTick(function () {
    console.log(counter); // This will increment counter with 1, counter = 3
});
console.log('something else ...'); // This will increment counter with 1, counter = 2

/*
 *   OUTPUT 
 */
starts ...
something else ...
3
```

Note that counter is **3** now.

So my conclusion is that `console.log()` inside `process.nextTick()` overwrite function is causing the recursion.

I hope this example will help you to clear the things :)

Comment: nice explanation